# How to fix error scroll horizontal moniter when convert psd to html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fix error scroll horizontal monitor.

here is demo http://baogiadientu.com/demo/.

As you see, scroll horizontal bar appears on monitor. I put overflow: hidden for `html` or body tag, no any scroll bar is appear. I want to eliminate scroll horizontal bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to hide the scroll bar use

```
html,body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But understand your image is `1360px` wide so that's why it's appearing. The user will still be able to scroll horizontally but you won't see the bar. You will have to adjust your design/css if you dont want them to scroll horizontally at all

Comment: I use some other moniter are wider than my moniter (13.3 inch) but why it's still appear? I think wider moniter has resolution than 1360px that it doesn't appear horizontal bar.

Comment: understand that monitor size in inches and resolution are two different things. When the size of the window is greater than 1360 the scroll bar doesn't show